# Can I use variables in assetManager.open() parametre?

Tags: android, variables, inputstream, android-assets

I'm trying to give the open function in assetManager, which is an instance from the AssetManager class, variable like this:

```
    String filename="\"file.xml\"";
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = assetManager.open(filename);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
    }
```

but it isn't working knowing that without variable it will work:

```
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = assetManager.open("file.xml");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
    }
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not working because of the ". You should use `String filename = "file.xml";`

When you use `"\"file.xml\""` you have the string *"file.xml"* which is different of the string *file.xml*

Comment: Thanks! but i'm still having a problem because i have a function that returns a string which will be stored in another string which is "filename", and then the variable "filename" will be in the open parameter.

Comment: Well i can only answer with the code you show. Please edit your question to add the code of this function. But i think you do a mistake between the `"toto"` that declare the string *toto* and `"\"toto\""` that declare the string *"toto"*.

Comment: Yes that was my problem. Thanks!